# SSH Public Key. disable login for specific user. pam?

Tags: 16.04, ssh, pam

So today my Server got hacked. But just a non sudoer user.

```
Nov 26 10:44:18 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal sshd[27188]: Accepted publickey for ... from hackerIP port 26394 ssh2: RSA SHA256:...
```

He started a screen and scanned networks nothing more. History is empty. He connected with some publickey tho I never added any keys. I know I should use ssh-keys instead of password. But my root never got compromised.
What I noticed in auth.log is this

```
Nov 26 19:01:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[12360]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ... by (uid=0)
Nov 26 19:01:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[12360]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ...
Nov 26 19:02:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[12368]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user ... by (uid=0)
Nov 26 19:02:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[12368]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user ...
```

I do not know if I am posting it in the wrong section to be honest.
I basically just want to know where to find the ssh-keys because my key folder is empty. How to disable remote login for that specific user (so that I only can connect over root and use 'su' command to login). And what to do with pam_unix.

Edit: Firtsly thanks for the huge help. I could undone everything the attacker did. And I disabled ssh-key login in sshd config so only passwords are valid. Failed2Ban is running as well and I am managing auth.log everyday manually.

Comment: The keys would be in the compromised user's home folder, ie `/home/baduser/.ssh`.

Comment: The second log snippet is the periodic command scheduler `cron` executing something. Look at everything in all `/etc/cron.*` as well as `/etc/crontab` and everything in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`. (Assuming here for a second that Ubuntu is like Debian in this regard, which it probably is.)

Comment: @bc2946088 i checked every user folder including the compromised one every single one was empty. probably he deleted the key?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling yeah I found that cronjob. and could stop that.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable a user from being able to remote into SSH, you have a couple configuration options directly from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

I personally favor using whitelists instead of blacklists for user accounts.  Here is why, using a whitelist only allows the explicit users to login where a blacklist, only prevents those users.  The whitelist is more complete in my opinion.

If you wanted admin, joe, and sally to remotely connect using SSH, the following directive added to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` would work.

```
AllowUsers admin joe sally
```

If you simply wanted to block `baduser` from connecting, use the following.

```
DenyUsers baduser
```

Either option, you need to `sudo service ssh restart` for the changes to take affect.

Comment: No need to `restart`, `reload` is sufficient.

Comment: I much prefer working with groups instead of users. Create a group `ssh-in` (or whatever you want to call it), then add `AllowGroups ssh-in` to sshd_config, then add the relevant users to it (using `vigr` or `usermod --append --groups ssh-in $USERNAME`)

Comment: That a slick way of doing it, @MichaelKjörling.  I don't have users on my systems other than myself, but if I did, I could see this being really beneficial.

Comment: @bc2946088 I'm willing to bet that you have plenty of users on your system other than yourself, but perhaps not **human** users. Even a clean Ubuntu installation (like almost every other Linux distribution out there possibly short of Linux From Scratch) sets up a number of service accounts. Granted those often don't have any valid password configured, but you never know...

Comment: Of course, though I simply whitelist my own user in ssh.  To create a group and add myself and still edit the configuration to whitelist the group would be additional steps with no seen benefit. @MichaelKjörling

Comment: @bc2946088 yeah. I thought about that too ofc. I would like to use AllowUsers and only allow login from a specific Ip but since I do not have a static one I cannot do that. Also I know it's the worst thing you can do to use root as remote login user.

Comment: When I use DenyUsers and someone tries to log into one tho existing or not is it still being logged in auth.log?

Comment: It should be logged to `/var/log/auth.log`, @Tom-OliverHeidel.

Answer (score 1):

Authorized keys are almost always in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys for the particular user.  You can find their home directory by doing the command `cd ~username`  The authorized keys file location can be changed in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config with a line like with `AuthorizedKeysFile /some/path/to/authorized_keys_file` so I would check both places.

You can disable login to that user by adding something like the following to your /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
AllowUsers root user
```

to only allow specific users or

```
DenyUsers user1 user2
```

to deny specific users.  There's a lot of other cool stuff like this, just read the sshd_config man page.
Usually root is not the account you want to ssh into because if it get's compromised, they can do anything.

Lastly, about the pam_unix thing, it's a cronjob.  You can find cronjobs in:

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs
/etc/crontab
/etc/cron.d
/etc/cron.hourly
/etc/cron.daily
/etc/cron.weekly
/etc/cron.monthly
```

Answer (score 0):

To harden your sshd config,

Disable login/passwd login :
in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM no
```

And you should disable root login (use sudo)

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

Ans as said by Bryce, use `AllowUsers` (but not root ;-)

There are some config you can do.

Comment: I am just curious about to turn off Pam since I do not really know what it does. I read something about two-factor auth and stuff and password checking. I will read man page tomorrow. But appreciate if someone can shortly sum up the important things.

Comment: PAM check login/passwd, so if you do not create a specific PAM config for ssh, PAM will alow login/passwd login. So to disable login/passwd login, you have to disable PAM during the ssh login sequence.